# How to reset a Linux VPS to 0 in one command?

Tags: mysql, linux, apache

I'm the owner of a VPS server and my goal is that the server reinstalls itself from zero, I explain:

- Delete all user (except root) and all file who are not Linux file (so delete all the non native file)
- Deinstall Apache and MySQL
- Reinstall Apache and MySQL and import table from external .sql file
- wget .tar of website and untar it

Except for the last step, I'm a little bit lost.

Comment: Run docker on your VPS. Build your base image in docker. Reset your docker image whenever you want.

Comment: You could build an orchestration script in Chef/Ansible/Salt/Puppet, and then run that after re-installing the base image via your VPS host control panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete all user
before you do that perform a backup of the user

```
sudo tar jcvf /user-backups/linux-user.tar.bz2 /home/linux-user
```

Issue delete user command along with deleteting user files

```
sudo deluser --remove-home linux-user
sudo deluser --remove-all-files linux-user
```

Remove mysql and apache completely

```
 sudo apt-get --purge remove mysql-client mysql-server mysql-common
 sudo apt-get autoremove

 sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql/
 sudo apt-get purge apache2*
```

Install apache

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Install mysql

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server libapache2-mod-auth-mysql
sudo mysql_install_db
sudo /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation

Enter current password for root (enter for none): 

OK, successfully used password, moving on...
```

Once mysql is installed, issue

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Enter password to login.

```
create database mysql_database;
exit
```

Go to the command prompt and issue

```
mysql -u root -p mysql_table < path_to_mysql_sql_file.sql
```

wget .tar of website and untar it
  when you're at `/var/www/html` issue

```
  sudo wget http://www.domain.com/the-tar-file.tar
```

Then issue this following command

```
  sudo tar xvf the-tar-file.tar
```

The command above will extract the files and folders from the tar archive.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir ! This gonna resolve my problems !

Answer (score 0):

Some general consideration :

- It's a bad idea to delete evey user, as linux need some of them for generic tasks (www-data i.e.). To list only the user you need, you can compare your current /etc/shadow file and the one in a new installation. Every difference can be deleted with "userdel the_username" without risk*
- Concerning linux files, i see 3 cases :

Website, personnal data ... Can be deleted (once saved)

Core linux files, programs ... Can be deleted (will be reinstalled)

Configuration files (apache config file, website .conf files, etc ...) : should be saved and reimported, as personnal data.

- removing Apache and mysql should be quite easy :

  sudo apt-get autoremove apache2 mysql-server mysql-client libmysqlclient15-dev mysql-common
- reinstall them is the almost same thing :

  sudo apt-get install apache2 mysql-server mysql-client libmysqlclient15-dev mysql-common

(* save everything before listenning to someone )

To get it working, you can make a bash script. Once the first part done (user deletion), it will be really easy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I can't upvote your post due of my reputation but thanks a lot !